# Dimensions of $\frak{sl}_n$-representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The dimension of any irreducible $\frak{sl}_n$-representation $V$ is clearly equal to the dimension of its dual representation $V^*$. Does the dimension of an irreducible $\frak{sl}_n$-representation determine it uniquely up to its dual? What happens for the $B,C$, and $D$ series?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recall that the dimension of the $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ representation indexed by partition $\lambda$ is the number of semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ with entries in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

You can check that there are 15 SSYTs of shape $(3,1)$ with entries in $\{1,2,3\}$, and similarly 15 SSYTs of shape $(4)$ with entries in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Furthermore these representations are not dual: $(3,1)=\omega_1+2\omega_2$ while $(4)=4\omega_1$.

So the answer is **no**: not even irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ representations are determined by their dimensions, up to duality.

Comment: But the fundamental irreps should still be determined by their dims/duality? This should follow from the dims being equal to those of the exterior powers?

Comment: That should be a simple check involving binomial coefficients, as you say.

Comment: @JakeWetlock: though note for Type $D_4$, by the symmetry of the Dynkin diagram the fundamental irreps corresponding to the leaf nodes all have the same dimension, but of course cannot all be dual to one another.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the weight diagrams of the two 15 dimensional $sl(3)$-reps mentioned by [Sam Hopkins](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385685):

1  1  1  1  1
    1  1  1  1
      1  1  1
        1  1
          1

and

1  1  1
  1  2  2  1
    1  2  1
      1  1

Comment: I feel silly saying this to a user with over 7 times my reputation, but this seems like it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: ... or rather a cw answer meant to be an extended comment?

Comment: An implicit point in this answer that might be useful to the OP (although it is standard stuff): in contrast to knowing the dimension, knowing all the weight space dimensions *does* determine the representation (indeed, whether it is irreducible or not). That's the whole point of the theory of weights and characters, etc.

Comment: Apologies for the breach in protocol. I've made it CW.